# jQuery.POST : Call WCF Service not being called !

Tags: wcf, jquery, wcf-client, jquery-post

As I am trying to make POST request to my `WCF service`, I am not being able to `POST the service request` and `can't get response.`

I'm using **WebHttpBinding** and my `WCF service is hosted in Windows service` with `PORT 8181`

**WCF Service Method:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/{cstid}/{deptid}/get/customer/?cstname={cstname}", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Customer CustomerGet(string cstid, string deptid, string cstname);
```

**JQuery POST Method**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8181/mysite/e48/91/get/customer/?',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);  // not getting anything  :(
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error :' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

Could anybody please let me know why I am not able to call this service and how would I resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using firefox with firebug?   is the post showing up in the console?  what does the response look like?

Comment: I don't have an answer but does this use the REST kit for WCF?

Comment: Is it typo that query string of your service url is missing in constructed jquery call?

Comment: I think there is a problem of CROSS DOMAIN posting, because I am running my MVC site with http://localhost:8080 PORT while my WCF service is hosted with http://localhost:8181 PORT... Any idea how would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your UriTemplate:

```
/{cstid}/{deptid}/get/customer/?cstname={cstname}
```

Your jQuery URL:

```
/e48/91/get/customer/?
```

Looks like you're missing the `cstname`, so the value at runtime will be null because query string parameters are not required to match a UriTemplate. You don't show your implementation, but I'm guessing however you look up the `Customer` is accepting null, but then not finding an actual instance and just returning null.

Comment: I think there is a problem of CROSS DOMAIN posting, because I am running my MVC site with http://localhost:8080 PORT while my WCF service is hosted with http://localhost:8181 PORT... Any idea how would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your UriTemplate is

```
 UriTemplate = "/{cstid}/{deptid}/get/customer/?cstname={cstname}",
```

You should at least be passing a parameter for {cstname}. For example, try this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost:8181/mysite/e48/91/get/customer/?',
data: { cstname: "nunu" },
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
processData: false,
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);  // not getting anything  :(
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error :' + textStatus);
}});
```

In my opinion, using WCF Web Http services for anything other than WebGet operations is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I think there is a problem of CROSS DOMAIN posting, because I am running my MVC site with http://localhost:8080 PORT while my WCF service is hosted with http://localhost:8181 PORT... Any idea how would I resolve this?

Comment: Yes. Try either (a) using tyoe: "GET" instead of POST, or (b) do not specify the contentType at all. For me, I have always gotten (a) to work. And for 3 string parameters, why do you need to do POST? It's much easier to use GET, and much less likely to fail, which is why I almost always use type: "GET". This is because it is very difficult to get a WCF service to work right with POST. Use WebGet not WebInvoke if possible